# How to get notification permission status (Swift)?

Tags: swift, notifications

I have this function but for some reason, it throws an error.

What could be the problem?

```
func notificationStatus() -> Bool {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        if(settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

**This is the error: "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"**

Comment: You can’t wait an asynchronous method to return its result. What you need is to add a completion handler to your method.

Comment: Then, how can I get the notification permission status? I am talking about the case user denies the prompt... Thanks for answering.

Comment: again you need to add a completion handler `func notificationStatus(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {` `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings {` `completion($0.authorizationStatus == .authorized)` `}` `}`

Comment: You are missing the "asynchrone concept". Add a print just before `return true` and one instead of `return false`, and see which one will appear first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Leo says in his comment, you can't return a result from an async function. (The function `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().center.getNotificationSettings()` returns immediately, before it has prompted the user to approve notifications. Once the user responds, getNotificationSettings calls its completion handler. Inside that completion handler, you need to call *your* completion handler.)

You need to rewrite your function to take a completion handler. Something like this:

```
func notificationStatus( completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        let authorized = settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized
        completion(authorized)
    } 
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
notificationStatus(completion: { authorized in
       print("authorized = \(authorized)")
   }
)
```

Or, using [**trailing closure syntax**](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-trailing-closure-syntax):

```
notificationStatus() { authorized in
   print("authorized = \(authorized)")
}
```

Note that as pointed out by Leo Dabus below, you can skip the parens in the function call when using trailing closure syntax:

```
notificationStatus { authorized in
   print("authorized = \(authorized)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: () it is not need either for the trailing closure syntax. `notificationStatus { authorized in
   print("authorized”, authorized) }`

Comment: Wow, I never realized that you could skip the parens in a function call when there was a trailing closure and the function doesn't take any parameters. Thank you. I learned something about a fundamental language feature that I thought I knew "cold." Thank you!

Comment: @DuncanC Perfectly explained solution. Kudos!